# Is there a class or library to get list of states for a given country?

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, statelist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Country, State, Province WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121117/country-state-province-webservice)

**This "orignal" link only shows web services or places I can get lists to insert manually. Does anyone know of a library / built in class / dll that wouldn't require hitting another server for the data and not require manual entry of each state?**

I am currently adding support for Canada, Mexico, and Brazil, (and potentially more soon) to an ASP.NET website. The user can input their physical address including their state via drop down list. I currently have the US states added manually like:

```
states.Add(new ListItem("Alabama", "AL"));
states.Add(new ListItem("Alaska", "AK"));
etc ...
```

Before I go ahead and start manually creating lists for the additional countries, is there some pre-built class or library out there that can give me a list of states by passing it a country code? Example: `someClass.getStatesFor("BR");` // would return a list/collection of states for Brazil.

Comment: Would a web service be acceptable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121117/country-state-province-webservice

Comment: Maxmind is also a good resource.  http://www.maxmind.com/

Comment: As an aside: not all countries consider their equivalent to "states" as an important part of an address. That is, if a website made me fill out a drop box with a province for my country as a required field I'd close the site on account of it being annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find the data you need on http://www.geonames.org. State information is referred to as *administrative subdivision*.

This data is available as a webservice, but you may also download it.
The data description can be found on this page: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

There are components for various languages, but I think those are to access the web services.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:
http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements

The ISO list is always up-to-date.

Hope these help.